# Meteor error just on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor, npm

I want to run meteor application on windows after developting it some time on mac. when I run `meteor` command it states this error:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- lather_headers, azure-graphapi, xml2json, node-forge, websocket, googleapis, request, path, gmail-api-create-message-body, request-promise, node-ews-noloop,
http-proxy...
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While building package npm-container:
   error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap: Command failed: gypnpm WARN enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\c\liso_service\packages\npm-container\.npm\package-new-1e8tkgh\package.json'
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No description
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No repository field.
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No README data
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No license field.
   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
   npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.3.4_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.3.4_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
   npm ERR! node v0.10.45
   npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

   npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   gypnpm WARN enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\c\liso_service\packages\npm-container\.npm\package-new-1e8tkgh\package.json'
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No description
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No repository field.
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No README data
   npm WARN package-new-1e8tkgh No license field.
   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
   npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.3.4_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.3.4_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
   npm ERR! node v0.10.45
   npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

   npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.



=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I can see what is the error message. But I do not know haw do I get directory `package-new-1e8tkgh` instead of just `package`

I have correct versions of node and npm, that are mentioned in error:

> npm ERR! node v0.10.45
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6

This was warking while I had meteor version 1.2.0.2 and I was using node version 0.10.40. But since meteor upgrade to 1.3.4.1 it stopped.

I also have visual studio 2012 and python 2.7 installed. ( as it says on some previous sources, that this was necessary to run and build meteor on windows. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829284/deploy-meteor-on-windows) one  )

OS is windows server 2012, I have tried on Win 7, 8 and 10 but it does not work. Event the old meteor version 1.2.0.2  was just working on Windows server 2012.

What should I do to get this working? Why is this happening at all. Should not I just install newer node version and go on. Like in this case from 0.10.40 to 0.10.45.

Please advise.

Comment: Meteor claimed windows was a first class development citizen, but I see more and more problems with it as versioning marches forward.  I would just bite the bullet and work on your mac, or a virtual machine running something like Ubuntu.

Comment: @AnthonyAstige the problem is that I have requirement to host final app on windows. Thus, I need to be able to successfully run meteor build on windows. Is there a problem if I build bundle on mac and start it as node app on windows? I will try now. But what do you suggest?

Comment: imo hosting Meteor on windows sounds like a world of pain I wouldn't want to touch.  The majority of the Meteor community runs on Linux, so there will likely be untested boundaries hosting Windows. I would probably suggest a cloud provider like AWS, Digital Ocean, or even Meteor's own Galaxy (though I don't know enough about your use case to say for certain / which precise direction to lean towards).