# EACCESS error when running meteor on Windows 10's VSCode

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor

I tried to deploy my project, but this error still happens. I have restarted net driver, disabled Windows Defender, changed permission on my directory, let VSCode have admin right, but this error still persists. I could not even run on CMD with admin rights. I could deploy using WSL it takes a very long time for deployment. How can I fix this?

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat 'C:\Users\mq003\Documents\myproject\.meteor\local\dev_bundle'
    at Object.statSync (fs.js:1132:3)
    at statOrNull (C:\Users\mq003\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\cli\dev-bundle.js:94:21)
    at getDevBundleDir (C:\Users\mq003\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\cli\dev-bundle.js:32:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mq003\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\cli\dev-bundle.js:142:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mq003\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\cli\dev-bundle.js:145:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'stat',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\mq003\\Documents\\myproject\\.meteor\\local\\dev_bundle'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see some options:

- try deploy on docker.
- restart `winnat` following this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67968597/6398044

- remove other processes on your meteor port (eg using kill-port npm package)
- change port of your meteor app

Generally in linux this error is connected with access to files, but on windows it seems to be connected with network issues. In all other threads `winnat` is mentioned, so if this will not help please add more context about your `winnat` config.

[Node.js port permission denied in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69903091/node-js-port-permission-denied-in-windows-10)

https://superuser.com/questions/1437780/how-to-fix-listen-eacces-permission-denied-on-any-port

You can read about deployment meteor on windows here and compare it with your:

[Deploy Meteor on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829284/deploy-meteor-on-windows)

https://forums.meteor.com/t/one-deployment-method-for-a-meteor-application-on-windows/13928